# Using the space next to tabs for displaying text and images

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside2

I have a `QTabWidget` as my 'central widget' and I would like to use the space that's left over after the tabs have been placed for displaying some text and an image (area in blue below):

[image: Usable area next to tabs]

I'm looking for pointers to solutions that will allow me to best make use this space; any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the `QTabWidget` into a `QTabBar` and a `QStackedWidget`, and connect them using `connect(tab_bar, &QTabBar::currentChanged, stacked_widget, &QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex);`. Then, you can add whatever next to the tab bar like this.

[image: Suggested layout]

Answer (score 0):

A good [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71033023/458116) from @Minh... that would provide quite a bit of flexibility. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649177/add-widgets-into-a-qtabwidget) suggested using the '[corner widget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTabWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTabWidget.setCornerWidget)' which sounded better since I won't lose some of the given functionality of `QTabWidget`.

I gave it a try and it does what I wanted; within my `QTabWidget` class, I now have:

```python
    # Image and text labels
    qlabel_img = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('image.png')
    qlabel_img.setPixmap(pixmap)
    qlabel_txt = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"Text under image")

    # Corner widget
    corner_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    corner_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    corner_layout.addWidget(qlabel_img)
    corner_layout.addWidget(qlabel_txt)
    corner_widget.setLayout(corner_layout)
    self.setCornerWidget(corner_widget)
```

and so `corner_widget` is displayed at the top right (right justified) of the tab widget.